# Directive compile function, adds html but then gets overwritten

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have an directive. I want it to read configuration options from a table head then build out the tbody tr with angular expressions (ng-repeat) at the compile stage.

I have debugged and can get to a stage where I can see the HTML in the DOM in firebug on a breakpoint after the insertion. I have also debugged the point where it is removed and its on the applyDirectivesToNode function. I can't figure out the correct configuration of transclude.

Here's a fiddle. Any help would be amazing. Line 32 is where I append the HTML http://jsfiddle.net/raff77/eGUhF/2/

```
  tBody.append(html);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made some changes to the original fiddle to make it work:

1. Use `datatable` instead of `data-table` in HTML
2. Line 22, use `find('th')` instead of `find('thead > tr > th')` because of the limitation of jqLite
3. Line 23, use `dataset` instead of `chartdata`
4. Line 32, use `tBody[0].innerHTML = html` instead of `tBody.append(html)`

Check the [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jaux/M388p/) out, I have "FIXED" comments in it to further clarify some of the issues.

Comment: Thanks, I am an idiot. Strange though I have JQuery installed so thought .html() would have worked. Best to use native JavaScript I suppose. Thanks again.